# Read/Write synchronizer , get the owner of the lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, monitors

Probably this is a simple question, but due to lack of some knowledge on C# I'm having a hard time finding a solution for this.

Here's the deal, I have to implement a semaphore with 5 methods, lockRead, lockWrite, releaseRead, releaseWrite and releaseLockWriter.

The names of the first four methods are quite self-explanatory, the last one is a method that releases a writer lock and acquires read lock atomically.

Now my problem here is that releaseRead, releaseWrite and releaseLockWriter can only be called by a thread that has acquired the read or write lock, respectively.

How can I know if the thread is the owner of the lock? A possible solution would be creating id's for each thread and passing them when acquiring lock and then when releasing passing the id again and check if the id is owner, but probably there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Is this a homework? why don't you use synchronization mechanisms already available like *ReaderWriterLock*.

Comment: The idea is to create all the logic to better understand locking mechanisms  . And yes it's homework, but I'm not asking anybody to solve it for me, I'm just asking if there's a way to know if a thread is owner of lock so it can release it.

Comment: Then Use the source code of *ReaderWriterLock* for a hint.

Comment: _"if there's a way to know if a thread is owner of lock so it can release it"_ -- I'm not aware of anything in the .NET API that exposes the thread or threads that have acquired a lock. If you're writing your own lock object, then of course you can include such a mechanism yourself. But Stack Overflow isn't a "write my code for me" site, and the answer to a question that starts out with "is there a way..." is always "yes". It's just that "the way" is sometimes harder and less feasible in some situations than in others.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm not asking anybody to write my code, I'm just asking if it's possible and if so how. And what I mean by how, is explaining a possible solution/algorithm , not coding anything for me. EZI said that I should take a look at ReaderWriterLock and that's what I'm doing. Before that I was reading this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810427.aspx).

Comment: _" if it's possible"_ -- of course it's possible. _"and if so how"_ -- that question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. There are many possible ways to do this, and your question doesn't include enough context or constraints to narrow it enough for anyone to know what the best/feasible/permissible approach would be in your particular scenario.